# Proof using the Markov property

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Consider a general chain with state space $S = {1,2}$ and write the transition probability as:  [image]
>
> Use the Markov property to show that $$P(X_{n+1} = 1) - \frac{b}{a+b} = (1-a-b) \bigl\{P(X_n = 1) - \frac{b}{a+b}\bigr\}$$
>
> and then conclude $$P(X_n = 1) = \frac{b}{a+b} + (1-a-b)^n \bigl\{P(X_0 = 1) - \frac{b}{a+b}\bigr\}$$
>   This shows that if $0 < a+b < 2$, then $P(X_n = 1)$ converges exponentially fast to its limiting value $b / (a+b)$.

I'm not really sure how to begin this proof. I've just begun to learn about the Markov property, and I'm not really sure how to use it in this way. Any push in the right direction (however small) is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the total probability formula:

$P(X_{n+1}=1)=P(X_{n+1}=1|X_n=1)P(X_n=1)+P(X_{n+1}=1|X_n=2)P(X_n=2)$

Then you take $P(X_{n+1}=1|X_n=1)=1-a$ and $P(X_{n+1}=1|X_n=2)=b$ from your transition matrix, and use $P(X_n=2)=1-P(X_n=1)$

... and you are going to be left with an equation in terms of $P(X_{n+1}=1)$, $P(X_n=1)$, $a$, and $b$.

Comment: Using this method I'm getting the following:

$$P(X_{n+1} = 1) = P(X_{n+1} = 1 | X_n = 1) P(X_n = 1) + P(X_{n+1} = 1 | X_n = 2) P(X_n = 2)$$ $=>$

$$P(X_{n+1} = 1) = (1-a)P(X_n = 1) + b(1-P(X_n = 1))$$

$=>$
$$P(X_{n+1} = 1) - b = (1-a-b)P(X_n = 1)$$

Am I missing something? Maybe I'm having a momentary lapse of reason but I'm not sure how to manipulate this to the needed equality.

Comment: Subtract on both sides $\frac{b(1-a-b)}{a+b}$ ?

Comment: Ahh, I see now - thank you!

Why exactly do we subtract this rather than keep the equality as $$P(X_{n+1} = 1) - b = (1-a-b)P(X_n = 1)$$ ?

Comment: Long story short, you have a first-order linear recurrence, with constant coefficients, something like $p_{n+1}=\alpha p_n + \beta$. Subtracting that term helps you to find a closed form of the solution, which is necessary for the part 2 of your question. You may google "first order inhomogeneous linear recurrence" for more details

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) for example